# Flutter, open the Text displayed inside a Card in an Alert dialog

Tags: flutter, android-alertdialog

in flutter, i'm trying to get the text in the card to be displayed in the Alert Dialog when the card is tapped just like in the pictures below:

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOid0.jpg)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85258.jpg)

I merely ask to be pointed in the right direction of how something like this would be acomplished. Although hand-helding would be appreciated, i ask atleast for where to start at.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You can wrap your card in an [Inkwell Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html), in `onTap` you can then create your [AlertDialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html). I hope I could point you in the right direction! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is having the `String` for the text of the card stored inside a variable, what you would then do is `onTap` of the card you call a function that you create and pass the variable that you stored the string of the text is `showMyDialog(textVariable)` which would call the function to display the dialog and then display the text using the `textVariable`.

I've attached a more accurate example to achieve what you want.
You can tweak the UI as u wish

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String displayText = "Same Text Everywhere";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: ()=> showMyDialog(context,displayText),
          child: Card(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: Text(displayText),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> showMyDialog(BuildContext context, String displayText) {
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          content: Text(displayText),
        );
      },
    );
  }


}
```

Comment: THANKS, THIS WORKED LIKE A CHARM.

 Next I tried to take a string User Input from a Text Field and display it in a card or some other widget on the screen but that failed miserably, always throwing an error that the bottom overflowed by an infinity pixels. I think is because i didnt use a future method and it tries to instanly display a variable which is empty and crushes.

Anyway, I suppose I need to use a future method for this to work, am I on the right track or totally off course?

Thanks again

Comment: Feel free to post a new question for other people searching question and if you want tag me and I'd gladly help. Also some code would always be appreciated! 
Make sure you do the right research before though to avoid any duplicate questions!